# After .append a row why .on is not working?

Tags: jquery

It work for first row as shown below code but after appending a row some how it is not working. I think it is not aware that a new row is created. I just stuck here
here is the code

```
<table id="Allitems" class="table table-bordered table-hover Ptable">
            <tbody class = "input_fields_wrap_addRow">
                <tr class ="inputdata3">
                    <td class ="inputdata">
                    </td>
                    <td class ="inputdata">
                        <input type="number" name="data[Invoice][itemQuantity][]" step="1" min="0" class="form-control Invquantity">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div id="inv_" class="inv_spacer" >
            <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
        </div>
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap_addRow"); //Fields wrapper
                var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
                $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
                    e.preventDefault();
                        $(wrapper).append('<tr class ="inputdata3"><td class ="inputdata"></td><td class ="inputdata"><input type="number" name="data[Invoice][itemQuantity][]" step="1" min="0" class="form-control Invquantity"></td></tr>'); //add input box

                });
            });


            $(function(){
                $('.inputdata3').on('keyup','.Invquantity',function(){
                    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                    alert("eded");
                });
            });
```

Comment: your `tr` is not added to the document yet when the listener is set, because it will be only after the click. Either set a listener at a higher level like answers suggest, or simply add the listener at the creation: `var el = $('<tr'>....); $(wrapper).append(el); el.on('keyup', ...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event needs to be delegated to static element that is to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached. As `inputdata3` dynamically generate thus event handler didn't worked.

Instead of `$('.inputdata3')` use `wrapper` cached variable or `input_fields_wrap_addRow` selector

```
$(".input_fields_wrap_addRow").on('keyup','.Invquantity',function(){})
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because you are checking for `.inputdata3`. JS code will get the first `.inputdata3` and will only work for first.

You need to change this line:

`$('.inputdata3').on('keyup','.Invquantity',function(){`

to:

`$('table#Allitems').on('keyup', '.Invquantity', function() {`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap_addRow"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    $(wrapper).append('<tr class ="inputdata3"><td class ="inputdata"></td><td class ="inputdata"><input type="number" name="data[Invoice][itemQuantity][]" step="1" min="0" class="form-control Invquantity"></td></tr>'); //add input box

  });
});


$('table#Allitems').on('keyup', '.Invquantity', function() {
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  alert("eded");
});

$(function() {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Allitems" class="table table-bordered table-hover Ptable">
  <tbody class="input_fields_wrap_addRow">
    <tr class="inputdata3">
      <td class="inputdata">
      </td>
      <td class="inputdata">
        <input type="number" name="data[Invoice][itemQuantity][]" step="1" min="0" class="form-control Invquantity">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="inv_" class="inv_spacer">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It might work, but not for the reason that was stated in the answer. `$('.inputdata3')` will get all elements with class `inputdata3`, not just the first: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: Which `inputdata3` are you pointing to, as I am not using that selector.

Comment: I was pointing to the row that was later appended which is not working as it is not attached to static element. now i am using 'input_fields_wrap_addRow ' instead of  'inputdata3' now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are attaching event listeners to your first `tr` which is rendered initially and event listener is attached to this `tr`. Newly added row does not have this even listener attached. You need to took advantage of event bubbling. So instead attach your event listner to your `tbody` as follow:

```
$('.input_fields_wrap_addRow').on('keyup','.Invquantity',function(){
     var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
     alert("eded");
 });
```

Here is a working snippet. You can run this snippet as is by clicking on `Run Code Snippet` button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap_addRow"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    $(wrapper).append('<tr class ="inputdata3"><td class ="inputdata"></td><td class ="inputdata"><input type="number" name="data[Invoice][itemQuantity][]" step="1" min="0" class="form-control Invquantity"></td></tr>'); //add input box

  });
  
  $('.input_fields_wrap_addRow').on('keyup', '.Invquantity', function() {
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  alert("eded");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Allitems" class="table table-bordered table-hover Ptable">
            <tbody class = "input_fields_wrap_addRow">
                <tr class ="inputdata3">
                    <td class ="inputdata">
                    </td>
                    <td class ="inputdata">
                        <input type="number" name="data[Invoice][itemQuantity][]" step="1" min="0" class="form-control Invquantity">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div id="inv_" class="inv_spacer" >
            <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting `$('.inputdata3')`, select the  *.input_fields_wrap_addRow* like this `$('.input_fields_wrap_addRow')`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a dynamically loaded element it wont get picked up, instead use:

```
$("body").on("keyup", ".Invquantity", function(){
    //code here
});
```

Hope this helps!